# Convergence of an exponent function

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

[Following the answer to this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438190/going-from-the-poisson-distribution-to-the-gaussian), it is claimed that we easily show the following convergence:

$$ \text{exp}(-\sqrt{\lambda}it + \lambda (e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1)) \rightarrow_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)$$

Which is proved by noting that the following expression holds:

$$ \exp\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \right) -1 = \frac{it}{\sqrt{\lambda}} - \frac{t^2}{2\lambda} + o(\lambda^{-1})$$

While I understand how the former was derived, my question is how does this prove the convergence?

Since in this case,

$$\lambda (e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1) =\lambda\frac{it}{\sqrt{\lambda}} - \frac{t^2}{2} + o(\lambda^{-1/2}) $$

And I can't see why the $\sqrt{\lambda} it$ member disappears at the limit here. Does it have to do anything with the imaginary part?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows that
$$
\exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}it + \lambda (e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1))=\exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}it+\sqrt{\lambda}it-\frac{t^2}{2}+\lambda o(\lambda^{-1}))=\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2}+\lambda o(\lambda^{-1})).
$$
We note that
$$
\lambda o(\lambda^{-1})\stackrel{\lambda\to\infty}{\to}0 \implies \exp(-\frac{t^2}{2}+\lambda o(\lambda^{-1}))\stackrel{\lambda\to\infty}{\to}\exp(-t^2/2)
$$
by continuity of  the exponential function.

Comment: Oh, that's right, the other $-\sqrt{\lambda}it$ was right in front of me.. Discarded it too soon. Thanks!